# accepts_nested_attributes_for causing SQLException

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I would like to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create an Article object that `has_many` Sections.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections, :order => "position", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
  validates_presence_of :name, :on => :create, :message => "An article must have a title"
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  acts_as_list :scope => "article"
  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Whenever the `:reject_if` condition accepts the nested attribute (if the `title` attribute is not `blank?`) I see a SQLException. Otherwise the Article will be created successfully without the associated Sections.

```
Parameters: {"article"=>{"name"=>"My Article", "category_id"=>"7", "sections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Section 1", "content"=>"Section 1 of my new article"}}}}

AREL (30.3ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ("content", "category_id", "position", "name") VALUES (NULL, 7, NULL, 'My Article')

Section Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE (article) ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 1

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: article: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE (article) ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 1
Completed   in 68ms
```

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong during the `Section Load` stage, since `WHERE (article)` is unexpected. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Worth noting: I'm experiencing the same issue with two other independent models with the same one-to-many relation. I'm using Rails 3.0.3

Comment: I assume that the model associations work find from the console? Try nested attributes from the console, and also try simplifying your associations/accepts_nested declarations, KISS.

Comment: Running `Article.create!({:name=>"Console Test", :sections_attributes=>[{:title=>"Section 1.1"}]})` into the console results in the same SQLException. I've tried reducing the accepts_nested declaration to its most simple form, specifying only the nested model name. As stated in the question, everything works when the `:reject_if` condition fails, or is not declared at all. The error only occurs when the nested object is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is your `acts_as_list :scope => "article"` call, as per [the acts_as_list docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_list/0.1.2/ActsAsList/ClassMethods%3aacts_as_list) if you provide a string, then the gem considers that to be SQL which it will use literally.  You wanted to use `:article` here - which tells `acts_as_list` to use the `:article` association.